# Uncaught TypeError: web3 is not a constructor. the blockchain website cannot connect to metamask

Tags: web3js, contract-development, metamask, ethereumjs, constructor

i have issue on web3 = new web3 (web3.currentProvider);

below is the code. it said web3 is not a constructor. is it like the capital letter issues?

the version of my web3 is "^1.3".

```
var contract = "";

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
console.log('inside web3')
Web3 = new Web3 (Web3.currentProvider);
} else {
console.log('else web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:4444/'));

}

window.ethereum.enable()
.then(function (accounts) {
    console.log(accounts[0]);

    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.getAccounts();
 
  var contractabi = new web3.eth.contract([
{ABI}])
```

Answer (score 0):

change your Constructor name to Uppercase

```js
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Current errors (updated code above) : 

MetaMask no longer injects web3. & Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAccounts')

Comment: If metamask is installed in your browser, it injects an ethereum object into your browser’s global window object. that will be accessing window.ethereum
https://dev.to/rounakbanik/building-a-web3-frontend-with-react-340c

Comment: okay. i only use metamask browser extension. i have to install to make it work? sorry, im still new about blockchain

Comment: why there is an error here: web3.eth.getAccounts();  ?